# Cannot delete list element by referring to variable

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dijkstra

I need to delete element from list 'to_do" with the smallest value in dictionary. Variable 'letter' = 's' and compiler says there is no such element in list 'to_do'. What do I miss?

```
to_do = ['s','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','z','w']
done = []

dict = {}
dict ['s'] = [0, ]
dict ['a'] = [999, []]
dict ['b'] = [999, []]
dict ['c'] = [999, []]
dict ['d'] = [999, []]
dict ['e'] = [999, []]
dict ['f'] = [999, []]
dict ['g'] = [999, []]
dict ['h'] = [999, []]
dict ['z'] = [999, []]
dict ['w'] = [999, []]


while to_do:
    value = 999
    count = 0
    for element in to_do:
        var = dict[element]
        if var[0] < value:
            value = var[0]
            letter = element
            #print(letter)
    index = to_do.index(letter)
    print(value)
    to_do.pop(to_do.index(letter))
```

Comment: first of don't use `dict` as a variable name since it is a built-in, use something else like `dictionary` or `dct`

Comment: you are iterating over a list while manipulating the same list with pop(). Consider separating those tasks using enum:

Comment: You could simply get the index of an item if You were to use `enumerate()` function and just then do sth like `to_do.pop(index)` and the loop would be sth like `for index, element in enumerate(to_do):`

Comment: also why do You use lists in the dictionary? they are not necessary in case You didn't know and also it is possible to just do this: `dct = {'a': value, 'b': 999, 'c': [999, []]}` or whatever values You need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug in your code is letter hasn't been reset after the removal to a different value.

```py
to_do = ["s", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "z", "w"]
done = []

dict_ = {}
dict_["s"] = [
    0,
]
dict_["a"] = [999, []]
dict_["b"] = [999, []]
dict_["c"] = [999, []]
dict_["d"] = [999, []]
dict_["e"] = [999, []]
dict_["f"] = [999, []]
dict_["g"] = [999, []]
dict_["h"] = [999, []]
dict_["z"] = [999, []]
dict_["w"] = [999, []]

letter = ""
while to_do:
    value = 999
    count = 0
    for element in to_do:
        var = dict_[element]
        if var[0] < value:
            value = var[0]
            letter = element
    if letter:
        index = to_do.index(letter)
        to_do.pop(to_do.index(letter))
        letter = ""
```

This will loop forever because you aren't changing anything, but I would assume that you have something missing that you haven't stated in your question.

Comment: btw what if it tries indexing an empty string which btw this list doesn't contain?

Comment: I just updated the code to include the condition to overcome this. Anyhow, the OP's question seems to be missing something because why looping forever without a stopping condition?

Comment: yes, exactly. Value 999 blocks loop in going forward. Thank you

Comment: I haven't finished the code  yet, so it misses some features.